# System for keep in memory role reaction messages even if bot reloading

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I need help with a discord bot in python, I have a command that allows to put a role reaction on a message.

It works perfectly but I would like to know if it is possible to make sure that the bot keeps in memory data entered by the users (role, message id and reaction) so that it continues to work even if I reload the bot ? I guess i need a database or something but if you could give me advices...

Code below

```
import discord
import discord.ext 
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime

bot = commands.Bot

class Automod(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    bot.reaction_roles = []

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        for role, msg, emoji in bot.reaction_roles:
            if msg.id == payload.message_id and emoji == payload.emoji.name:
                await payload.member.add_roles(role)
    
    #SET REACTION ROLE
    @commands.command(name="p!set-reaction", aliases=["set-reaction"])
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def set_reaction(self, ctx, role: discord.Role=None, msg: discord.Message=None, emoji=None):
        """➡️ Set a role reaction on message """
        if role != None and msg != None and emoji != None:
            await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
            bot.reaction_roles.append((role, msg, emoji))
            await ctx.message.delete()
        
        else:
            await ctx.send("**Error:** Missing arguments, **[p!set-reaction <Role Name> <Message ID> <Emoji>]**")

    @set_reaction.error
    async def set_reaction_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send("**Error:** You must have `administrator` permission to do that. ❌")
```

Comment: I hope its clear but dont be shine to ask me more details...

Comment: If you're not saving any sensitive date, then [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) might be the simplest way to organize and save the data.